# ionic 3 creating a semi transparent overlay on ion-content

Tags: css, angular, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 angular to build my app. So, as a requirement I have a background image globally on all the pages. for which i modified app.scss as:

```
.app-bg{
    background-image: url('../assets/images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

this is used for ion-content like:

```
<ion-content padding class="app-bg" >
```

now on some of the pages I require a semi transparent layer to improve visibility of the actual contents.

so, how do i do that?  I tried to add another background with some style sheet like

```
<ion-content padding text-center  class="app-bg" style="background-image: url('assets/images/overlay.png');display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,0.70);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

but this does not seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Should do the trick:

```
<ion-content 
.....
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
>
```